# How to invoke a solution pool and access all the solutions in cplex using PYOMO ? this is the structure of my pyomo code

Tags: python, cplex, pyomo, cplex-python-api

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
opt = SolverFactory('cplex', executable = cplex_executor_path)
model.x = Var(ftHc, within = NonNegativeIntegers)
model.y = Var(ftHc, within = NonNegativeIntegers)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = xyz, sense=pyo.minimize)
model.C1 = Constraint(abc, rule=abc_rule)
results = opt.solve(model,tee=True)
```

I have tried to access it this way

```
for v in model.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

but I am getting an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'ConcreteModel' object has no attribute 'iter_integer_vars'
```

Comment: Maybe this [thread](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/639) would be helpful.